# Abline error in R for multiple regression with interaction variable

Tags: r, plot, regression, abline

I want two different lines for men and women in the same plot but I always get non-sense lines when I run this code. What is the problem and how can I solve it

```
library(wooldridge)

attach(wage1)

MODEL3=lm(log(wage)~educ+female+female*educ+exper+expersq+tenure+tenursq)
summary(MODEL3)

fix(wage1)
id <- wage1$female >= 1


plot(wage1$educ[!id], wage1$wage[!id],
     pch = 20,
     col = "red",
     main = "",
     xlab = "Class Size",
     ylab = "Test Score")


points(wage1$educ[id], wage1$wage[id],
     pch = 20,
     col = "green")


coefs <- MODEL3$coefficients


abline(coefs[1], coefs[2],
       col = "red",
       lwd = 1.5)


abline(coef = c(coefs[1] + coefs[3], coefs[2] + coefs[4]),
       col = "green", 
       lwd = 1.5 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model predicts `log(wages)`, but you are plotting the untransformed `wages` as the points on your plot with the `abline` values representing the predicted `log(wages)`, which therefore don't match. If you use `log(wages)` for the y axis of your plot, the lines make more sense:

```r
library(wooldridge)

attach(wage1)

MODEL3=lm(log(wage)~educ+female+female*educ+exper+expersq+tenure+tenursq)

id <- wage1$female >= 1


plot(wage1$educ[!id], log(wage1$wage[!id]),
     pch = 20,
     col = "red",
     main = "",
     xlab = "Class Size",
     ylab = "Log of Test Score")


points(wage1$educ[id], log(wage1$wage[id]),
     pch = 20,
     col = "green")


coefs <- MODEL3$coefficients


abline(coefs[1], coefs[2],
       col = "red",
       lwd = 1.5)


abline(coef = c(coefs[1] + coefs[3], coefs[2] + coefs[4]),
       col = "green", 
       lwd = 1.5 )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh, Yes I totally forget this. Thanks for your answer. Have a good day.